# Seeking a library to show nice alerts in WPF

Tags: wpf

I would like to show a message box in a fancy way in my WPF app: do you know any component/library to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Extended WPF toolkit has the [`MessageBox` control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox&referringTitle=Home) which has a fairly customizable appearance.

Answer (score 2):

There are several stylish message box available in wpf some of them are.
[sample 1](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2011/04/wpf-stylist-message-box.html)
[sample 2](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/12/wpf-messagebox-custom-control.html)
[sample 3](http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/05/extended-wpf-toolkit-new-messagebox-control/)
[sample 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper.aspx)
[sample 5](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are very nice dialogs in Material Design for XAML (WPF).
Download the sample program and go to Dialogs from the "Burger" menu (top left corner).
Some examples are shown here: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs